# Package appium or any selenium android project into .apk file

Tags: python, android, selenium, automation, appium

I have been trying to make a apk out of my appium project on android studio but i does not run on phone, i actually want to run automation directly on my phone as an app instead of using pc but two problems.

1. I need an active appium server.
2. Adb device name
3. If i import selenium or appium on the top of my code and convert my project into .apk file and install it on my phone, it does not work, no error just simply quits.

I can manage problem no.1 but what about 2 and 3, is it even possible, is there any alternate to make a automation app that runs on phone not via pc but as an app.

I just need to know if it can be done or not, if yes then how but if no then i guess i will finally stop. :P

Tools i tried.
1. Appium
2. Robotium
3. Python kivy

Comment: Did you make logs with buildozer? Did you put that libs to the requirements in the spec file?

Comment: No i don't remember doing something like that, can you please explain more?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Did you make your project with Kivy? If so, you made an apk with buildozer, right?

Comment: yes but after installing when i tried to run the app it simply crashes, no errors or messages. i even hosted a live appium server but it did not work inside phone. i just want to make an app that automatically likes or posts comments on instagram.

Comment: for some reason selenium based automation does not work inside the phone as an app.

Comment: Of course it won't show you the errors by itself. You should connect your phone to pc with ADB and run `buildozer android debug deploy run logcat`, then you'll see the errors in the console.

Comment: alright trying it.